# Controlling Yaml Serialization Order in Python

Tags: python, yaml

How do you control how the order in which PyYaml outputs key/value pairs when serializing a Python dictionary?

I'm using Yaml as a simple serialization format in a Python script. My Yaml serialized objects represent a sort of "document", so for maximum user-friendliness, I'd like my object's "name" field to appear first in the file. Of course, since the value returned by my object's `__getstate__` is a dictionary, and Python dictionaries are unordered, the "name" field will be serialized to a random location in the output.

e.g.

```
>>> import yaml
>>> class Document(object):
...     def __init__(self, name):
...         self.name = name
...         self.otherstuff = 'blah'
...     def __getstate__(self):
...         return self.__dict__.copy()
... 
>>> doc = Document('obj-20111227')
>>> print yaml.dump(doc, indent=4)
!!python/object:__main__.Document
otherstuff: blah
name: obj-20111227
```

Comment: For the record, there is a similar question (asked a couple of years after this one) here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/16782112/877069

Comment: Since this question was asked Python `dict` retains the order that the keys are added.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Took me a few hours of digging through PyYAML docs and tickets, but I eventually discovered [this comment](https://web.archive.org/web/20170308231702/http://pyyaml.org/ticket/29) that lays out some proof-of-concept code for serializing an OrderedDict as a normal YAML map (but maintaining the order).

e.g. applied to my original code, the solution looks something like:

```
>>> import yaml
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>> def dump_anydict_as_map(anydict):
...     yaml.add_representer(anydict, _represent_dictorder)
... 
>>> def _represent_dictorder( self, data):
...     if isinstance(data, Document):
...         return self.represent_mapping('tag:yaml.org,2002:map', data.__getstate__().items())
...     else:
...         return self.represent_mapping('tag:yaml.org,2002:map', data.items())
... 
>>> class Document(object):
...     def __init__(self, name):
...         self.name = name
...         self.otherstuff = 'blah'
...     def __getstate__(self):
...         d = OrderedDict()
...         d['name'] = self.name
...         d['otherstuff'] = self.otherstuff
...         return d
... 
>>> dump_anydict_as_map(Document)
>>> doc = Document('obj-20111227')
>>> print yaml.dump(doc, indent=4)
!!python/object:__main__.Document
name: obj-20111227
otherstuff: blah
```

Answer (score 21):

**New Solution** (as of **2020** and PyYAML 5.1)

You can dump a dictionary in its current order by simply using

```
yaml.dump(data, default_flow_style=False, sort_keys=False)
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it's so great to know that such a simple option exists in the latest version. Just made my day!

Comment: Please upvote this to the top solution to help others avoid wasting time on custom solutions now that it's built in to the library.

Comment: I couldn't find this key word argument documented in https://pyyaml.org/wiki/PyYAMLDocumentation

Answer (score 6):

I think the problem is when you dump the data.
I looked into the code of PyYaml and there is a optional argument called `sort_keys`, setting that value to `False` seems to do the trick.

Comment: This answer is what I was looking for. If you set `sort_keys` to `False`, PyYaml will respect your dictionary ordering.
```python
yaml.dump(data, file, sort_keys=False)
```

Answer (score -10):

The last time I checked, Python's dictionaries weren't ordered. If you really want them to be, I strongly recommend using a list of key/value pairs.

```
[
    ('key', 'value'),
    ('key2', 'value2')
]
```

Alternatively, define a list with the keys and put them in the right order.

```
keys = ['key1', 'name', 'price', 'key2'];
for key in keys:
    print obj[key]
```

Comment: Like my post says, I know Python dictionaries are unordered. Unfortunately, there's a big difference in Yaml readability between a dictionary and a list of tuples, so this won't work in my case.

Comment: Python dictionaries are ordered as of 3.6