# How to load a YAML file in Python while preserving the original order

Tags: python

I want to laod a YAML-file to a dict.
Everything I found is outdated, since Python 3.6 changed dicts to be ordered by insertion.
What would be the proper way to do it?

Comment: Would list `[(index, line)]` make sense?

Comment: You could have a look at OrderedDict for this purpose: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16782112/can-pyyaml-dump-dict-items-in-non-alphabetical-order

Comment: @SerejaBogolubov My dict is nested. I'm not really sure whether this would work. I would prefer a dict, especially since they preserve order now. I want to read the yaml, change some values and then dump it again. I think this would be easiest with a dict. (Please make different suggestions if you think, they would work)

Comment: @NicoMüller What is the difference between Dict and OrderedDict, now that dicts are ordered by insertion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to do that with ruamel.

```
import ruamel.yaml

yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML(typ='safe')
with open(path_to_file) as file:
    my_dict = yaml.load(file)
```