# Python: nested dict and specification in one key

Tags: python, dictionary, nested, yaml

I need to make a yaml file with a dict and a specific format.
The desired format of the yaml file would be:

```
classification:
- type: 4
  probability: 1.0
```

So far I created a dict with the following:

```
dic = {
    'classification': {
        'type': 4,
        'probability': 1.0
    }
```

which creates the following yaml file:

```
classification:
  type: 4
  probability: 1.0
```

What do I need to do to get the `-` in front of `type`?

Comment: Have you tried '- type': 4,  in your dictionary?

Comment: Are you using an external library, e.g., [pyyaml](https://pyyaml.org/wiki/PyYAMLDocumentation), to convert your dictionary to YAML, or have you written your own converter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using [PyYAML](https://pyyaml.org/), the hyphen gets added to the output for items within a list, so if you had:

```py
dic = {
    'classification': [  # start a list
        {
            'type': 4,
            'probability': 1.0
        }
    ]
}
```

then the output would be:

```py
import yaml

yaml.dump(dic, sys.stdout)

classification:
- probability: 1.0
  type: 4
```

Note that YAML seems to sort the dictionary keys alphabetically by default. To have it not sort the keys, you would [instead](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55171433/1862861) do:

```py
yaml.dump(dic, sys.stdout, sort_keys=False))

classification:
- type: 4
  probability: 1.0
```