# Make ordered dicts behave like normal dicts in yaml.dump output

Tags: python, dictionary, yaml, pyyaml, ordereddictionary

When serializing an `OrderedDict` with `yaml.dump()`  the output is quite difficult to comprehend due to the many dashes:

```yaml
refine: !!python/object/apply:collections.OrderedDict
- - - root
    - Wuhan/Hu-1/2019
  - - clock_rate
    - 0.0007
  - - clock_std_dev
    - 0.0003
```

Is there a way to make `yaml.dump()` serialize `OrderedDict`s just like normal `Dict`s? What I want is the much more readable:

```yaml
refine:
  root: Wuhan/Hu-1/2019
  clock_rate: 0.0007
  clock_std_dev: 0.0003
```

Do I need to iterate through the entire variable (it's composed of hundreds of dicts, the above is just an excerpt) and cast all `OrderedDict`s as `Dict`s or is there an in-built feature of `yaml.dump()` or a similar library that does this for me?

Comment: If speed is not an issue, I'd personally just recursively convert any ordered dicts to dicts. Also note that in Python 3 the dicts are ordered anyway, so you may not even need to do it this way.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use OrderedDict as an input in yaml.dump or yaml.safe\_dump?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42518067/how-to-use-ordereddict-as-an-input-in-yaml-dump-or-yaml-safe-dump)

Comment: @Peter *[Python 3.7](/q/39980323/4518341)

Comment: I mean, is there some problem with iterating over your list and converting to dict? It seems trivial.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga it's a big dict of dicts and lists, nested many levels deep. Can iterate over it but it needs a custom function, unless you know of a module?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `ruamel.yaml` as drop in replacement for `PyYAML` solved the problem instantly. `OrderedDict`s are no longer represented as lists in the output.

This code:

```py
import ruamel.yaml

yaml=ruamel.yaml.YAML()
yaml.dump()
```

Produces the much neater output:

```yaml
refine: !!omap
- root: Wuhan/Hu-1/2019
- clock_rate: 0.0007
- clock_std_dev: 0.0003
```